# QGIS 3.22.6 Add letters to check boxes instead of ticks when using value relation widget

Tags: qgis, polygon, layers, select, valuerelation

I am using QGIS 3.22.6. I have added a species list to a polygon layer using the value relation widget. For each feature I am able to tick/select which species are present within the polygon. Rather than just tick that they are present I would like to add a letter to the box instead of a tick to show whether the species is Dominant (D) Abundant (A) Frequent (F) Occasional (O) Rare (R). Is this possible?